# Android: Files from other application through dropbox, photos etc

Tags: android, file, android-intent, xamarin

I have an intent filter which have an action send and action view, and currently accepting all mime-type

```
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionSend, Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new string[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "*/*")]
```

I tried to pick a file from either dropbox or photos application I have installed externally not open through my application. When I debug on my application, the content of the intent I received was null e.g. the action, data.

[image]

I have no problem receiving file from Gallery or some other app like Explorer.

Comment: This looks like an intent filter from code, you have to declare your activity filters within your Manifest most likely.

Comment: i am using xamarin.  i thought filter is placed on activity class as an attribute on xamarin

Comment: `intent filter which have an action send and action view, $`. What have these to do with picking a file?

Comment: when going to dropbox or other application, they can select a file and share to other apps. May be I shouldn't call it picking file but sharing content.

Comment: Never mind, the dropbox and one other app send the intent to OnNewIntent.